# Como se Carga un dataList con un DataSet

Tags: c#

Es una pregunta simple, pero la desconozco. Se cargar un datalist con un dataTable, pero no con un dataSet

```
clases.Agencia objAgencia = new clases.Agencia();
DataTable dtAgencia = new DataTable();
dtAgencia = objAgencia.ObtenerListadoAgenciaNones();
IdAgencia.DataSource = dtAgencia;
IdAgencia.DisplayMember = "Nombre".Trim();
IdAgencia.ValueMember = "idAgencia";
objAgencia = null; dtAgencia = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he visto, indicando el número de consulta hecha en el procedimiento almacenado

```
dsPlantilla.Tables[2]
```

Comment: DataSet es un conjunto de tablas, lo que haces al final es coger una tabla del conjunto...en este caso la que esta en la posición 2 . Para luego asignarla al .DataSource del componente que quieras cargar.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los nombres de las tablas en un dataset:

```
private void Ver(DataSet Basedatos)
{
    // recoremos las tablas en el conjunto
    foreach(DataTable tabla in Basedatos.Tables)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tabla.TableName);
    }
}
```

Para obtener la posición dentro del DataSet de una tabla por su nombre(MiTabla):

```
dsPlantilla.Tables.IndexOf("Mitabla");
```

Para obtener la tabla dentro del DataSet  por su nombre(MiTabla):

```
var index=dsPlantilla.Tables.IndexOf("Mitabla");
var dt=dsPlantilla.Tables[index];
```

Pero también puedes:

```
var dt=dsPlantilla.Tables["Mitabla"];
```

Ejemplo de como se crean las tablas dentro de un dataset:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(  
  "SELECT * FROM Clientes", basedatosConnection);
SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter(  
  "SELECT * FROM Pedidos", basedatosConnection);   

  
DataSet Ventas = new DataSet();  
  
sda1.Fill(Ventas, "Clientes");  
sda2.Fill(Ventas, "Pedidos");
```

Y Finalmente cargar los datos de clientes a una vista(DataList,GridView... gv):

```
       gv.DataSource = Ventas.Tables[0];
       gv.DataBind();
```

o

```
       gv.DataSource = Ventas.Tables["Clientes"];
       gv.DataBind();
```

o pasando el dataset, que te cojera la primera tabla

```
   gv.DataSource = Ventas;
   gv.DataBind();
```

Para ver como enlazar las dos tablas en una vista:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189997/Gridview-inside-Gridview-in-asp-net-Csharp